# Unable to invoke props function passed to children in a loop reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I am just trying to create a comment box and comment board which contain multiple comments.

Each comments have one inputbox, button(save,edit) and button(remove). I have passed function made in board named updateComment to Component Comment as props.

Now When I am trying to execute save of child function in which I have called parent function updateComment using this.props.updateComment
it is giving me error can't read property of undefined.

I have searched for similar question on stackoverflow but I am unable to solved this proplem.

My app.js code is as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Home } from './home.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header/>
            <Board />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments:[
            "My name is brijesh",
            "My name is santosh",
            "My name is manoj"
        ]}
    };
    removeComment(i) {
        console.log("going to remove element i",i);
        var arr = this.state.comments;
        arr.splice(i,1);
        this.setState({comments:arr});
    };
    updateComment(newComment, i) {
        var arr = this.state.comments;
        arr[i] = newComment;
        this.setState({comments:arr});
    };
    render() {
        return (
             <div className="board">
                {
                    this.state.comments.map(function(text,i) {
                         return (
                            <Comment key ={i} index = {i}
                                updateComment={() => {this.updateComment}}
                                removeComment={() => {this.removeComment}}>
                                    {text}
                            </Comment>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Comment extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            edit: false
        };
    };
    edit(){
        this.setState({edit:true});
        console.log("you clickced on edit0");
    };
    save(){
        this.setState({edit:false});
        var newText = this.refs.newText.value;
        this.props.updateComment(newText, this.props.index);
        console.log("you clickced on edit0",newText);
    };
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
    render() {
            if(this.state.edit) {
                return (
                <div>
                    <div className="comment">
                        <input type="text" ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children} onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } />
                        <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="comment">
                        <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
                        <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
   } 
}

export default App
```

And my main.js looks like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';


ReactDOM.render(
    ( < App / > ), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I have also created fiddle also.

https://jsfiddle.net/aubrijesh/k3h2pcnj/#&togetherjs=uEI7TFnJD1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that DOMZE is on the right track but you should also bind the function in the map statement. In my opinion arrow functions makes it much easier to keep track of what *this* refers to.

```js
class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments:[
            "My name is brijesh",
            "My name is santosh",
            "My name is manoj"
        ]}
    };
    removeCommment(i) {
        console.log("going to remove element i",i);
        var arr = this.state.comments;
        arr.splice(i,1);
        this.setState({comments:arr});
    };
    updateComment(newComment, i) {
        var arr = this.state.comments;
              console.log("new Comment");
        arr[i] = newComment;
        this.setState({comments:arr});
    };
    render() {
        return (
             <div className="board">
                {
                    this.state.comments.map((text,i) => {
                         return (
                            <Comment key ={i} index = {i}
                                updateComment={() => {this.updateComment}}
                                removeComment={() => {this.removeComment}}>
                                    {text}
                            </Comment>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Comment extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            edit: false
        };
    };
    edit(){
        this.setState({edit:true});
        console.log("you clickced on edit0");
    };
    save(){
        this.setState({edit:false});
        var newText = this.refs.newText.value;
        this.props.updateComment(newText, this.props.index);
        console.log("you clickced on edit0",newText);
    };
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
    render() {
            if(this.state.edit) {
                return (
                <div>
                    <div className="comment">
                        <input type="text" ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children} onChange={ this.handleChange} />
                        <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="comment">
                        <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
                    <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
   } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LPL, but I getting same error 
"Cannot read property 'updateComment' of undefined" on save button click.
I have update my full code also.

Comment: @BrijeshVishwakarma can you show me your new code? As you can see if you run the code snippet I submitted there is no error on saving so it's hard to help without seeing your update.

Comment: I have also added fiddle also. You can view it is giving same error in fiddle also.

Comment: @BrijeshVishwakarma ok just switch `this.state.comments.map(function(text,i) {`to `this.state.comments.map((text,i) => {` and you're good

Comment: Thank you dude.You helped me alot.
Can you explain why that was not working?
why using normal map function and "this.updateComment.bind(this)" was not working?

Comment: @BrijeshVishwakarma Of course , it's because the inside of an arrow function shares the same `this`as it's surrounding code. So writing 
`const foo = function() {
  const bar = () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
}`
with arrow functions notation is the exact same thing as writing
`var foo = function foo() {
  var _this = this;
  var bar = function bar() {
    console.log(_this);
  };
};`
As you can see, with arrow function notation the `this` of the bar-function is translated to the `this` of the the foo-function. That's why you're now able to reach the correct `this`.

Comment: Try playing around in [this environment](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20foo%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&playground=true) and you'll get a grip of it.

Comment: Thanks @LPL for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

update your render method

```
    let self = this;
     return (
                 <div className="board">
                    {
                        self.state.comments.map(function(text,i) {
                             return (
                                <Comment key ={i} index = {i}
                                    updateComment={() => {self.updateComment}}
                                    removeComment={() => {self.removeComment}}>
                                        {text}
                                </Comment>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
   )
```

Comment: Thank you @Ravi Teja.
That is working.
Can you explain why exjactly??

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the class to the function, so that it knows what "this" is

```
render() {
    return (
         <div className="board">
            {
                this.state.comments.map(function(text,i) {
                     return (
                        <Comment key ={i} index = {i}
                            updateComment={this.updateComment.bind(this)}
                            removeComment={this.removeComment.bind(this)}>
                                {text}
                        </Comment>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note that you may want to do those bindings in the constructor so that it doesn't bind at each and every render

Comment: Thank for early answer @DOMZE,
but it is not working giving same error.
I have also tried to pass 'this' in map function like this.

this.state.comments.map(function(text,i) {
                     return (
                        <Comment key ={i} index = {i}
                            updateComment={this.updateComment.bind(this)}
                            removeComment={this.removeComment.bind(this)}>
                                {text}
                        </Comment>
                    )
                },this)

But this also not working.